# Question Limit Per Month

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, rate-limiting

Just to clarify, hypothetically if I asked 50 questions on the last day of a month would my quota of questions reset to 50 the next day?

**Edit.** Suppose I had asked 44 questions. On the last day of the month I asked 6 more questions. Then on the next day my quota would reset to 50?

Comment: Independently of the answer of this question, *please do not do that*.

Comment: @Mariano: Fortunately, he can't. He can only ask 6 a day, 50 per month, according to [Jeff's answer here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/do-we-limit-how-often-someone-may-ask-about-their-homework/2303#2303).

Comment: You might want to look at this page: [Those who asked the most quetions](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1251/top-askers-with-score) ask about 10-20 questions a month, so you're already way beyond that.

Comment: @Theo: Wow, so that list is sorted by total questions asked?

Comment: A related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit

Comment: @Michael: Yes, sorted by number of questions and name.

Comment: @Jonas: following a trail that started with your link led me to some of the most enjoyable minutes of my life. Thank you.

Comment: @mixedmath: You're welcome.  Part of me is curious about this trail of yours, while part of me thinks it is best left to the imagination.

Comment: Maybe it is also useful to know that deleted questions are counted into the quota, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102269/hit-the-50-questions-limit-with-less-than-50-questions).

Answer (score 21):

The limit is not based on calendar months, simply the last 30 days.

Comment: Thank goodness.

Comment: And is the 6 limit similarly based on the last 24 hours?

Comment: @gedgar yes that is so

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled how these limits actually work. We currently have a [user that keeps asking and asking](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/12796/victor). If I'm not miscounting, he asked 9 questions within the last 21 hours. So I'm confused about this 6 questions a day limit.