# How is this restriction of 50 questions in 30 days calculated in Mathematics Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I have started asking questions since April, the 3rd and today is May, the 3rd and I have already asked 50 questions so far in this period. Reason behind this is that I have been constantly solving critical problems and needing some help from experts since I stay in a very backward corner of the world and getting any help from any person is next to impossible. Thanks to the advent of technology that has helped some of us a lot through forums like this.There are,I have seen, many opinions regarding this. Some suggest the restriction should be more stringent. But imagine a student from a remote corner of the world attempting to learn Math-how much havoc will this restriction pose on him/her? . **By the bye I inquired  to know how  this restriction is calculated? I mean on May the 4th i.e tomorrow, should I be allowed to ask a question? Or it will henceforth be restricted?**

Comment: Is this your question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138893/does-the-50-questions-in-30-days-rate-limit-mean-30-calendar-days-or-720-hour?

Comment: @ user222031  No.This is not mine. I have not asked that question:

Comment: I mean does that post answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did thankyou. Actually I needed to confirm whether this restriction is rolling or not-meaning tomorrow I have the streak started from 4th April till tomorrow and so on. Thankyou. Today I was blocked to ask a question giving me that message I was beyond the limits. There is one more thing. See I have contributed MSE with some very good quality of questions which were neither duplicate and as you can see very few of my OPs are poorly voted as I put atleast a few hours on that problem but as you know time is of the essence . So does that contribution not count here? I wonder @ user222031

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of: [Question Limit Per Month](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2464).